# Storing/versioning large amount of JSON objects

Tags: json, database, version-control, storage

Our cloud service deals with chunks of JSON data (`item`) which is being manipulated all the time. It can be changed as fast as every second.

At the moment `item` is JSON object that is being modified all the time. Now we need to implement versioning of these items as well.

Basically, every time request to modify the object arrives, it is modified, saved to DB and then we also need to store that version somewhere. So later on you will be able to say "give me version 345 of this item".

My question is - what would be the ideal way to store this history. Mind you, we do not need to query or alter the data once saved, all we need is to load it if necessary (0.01% of time) - the data is meaningless blob basically.

We are researching multiple approaches:

- Simple text files (file system)
- Cloud storage (eg S3)
- Version control (eg GIT)
- Database (any)
- Vault (For example Vault from hashicorp)

Main problem is that since items are updated every second, we end up with a lot of blobs. Consider - 100 items, updated every second - thats 8,640,000 records in a single day. Not to mention 100rps for the DB.

Do you have any recommendation as to what would be the optimal approach? We need it to be scalable, fast, reliable, encryption out-of-the-box would be great plus.

Comment: Since you have a DB, use it. It will solve your problem. Save json objects in a table with a version column. It will fulfill all your needs. Maybe in the future you need to search inside the json, and this aproach allows it.

Comment: @AlejandroPérezFals We are not convinced if DB is the best approach. Main problem is that since items are updated every second, we end up with a lot of blobs. Consider - 100 items, updated every second - thats 8640000 records in a single day. Not to mention 100rps for the DB.

Comment: @AlejandroPérezFals Also, we will not be querying the data ever. This will be simply for audit purposes and/or restoration of the data at any point in past. If we would ever consider querying these items, we would query the latest - saved in the database separately.